# https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize does not work

Tags: twitter

I try on the URL : https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXX and it worked

I then hit on the Authorize APP button but it brough me to this :

Example Domain This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

More information...

I have no idea of what's going on? Could you shed some lights on what I did wrong?

Thanks much!!

Comment: Let's see the rest of your code? You obviously have `example.com` somewhere either in your code or in your app details.